# template parameters and decltype

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, decltype

codes as follows:
'''

```
template<typename T>
struct has_no_destroy{
    template<typename C>
        
        static char test(decltype(&C::no_destroy));
    
    template<typename C>
        static int32_t test(...);
    
    
    const static bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == 1;
};

struct A{
    
}; 

struct B{
    void no_destroy(){
    }
};

struct C{
    int no_destroy;
    
};

struct D:B{
    
};
void test(){
    std::cout<<has_no_destroy<A>::value<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<has_no_destroy<B>::value<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<has_no_destroy<C>::value<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<has_no_destroy<D>::value<<std::endl;
}
```

'''

i just want to know why to use test(0) rather than test(1),if i run the first,results ok!but second failed to my expectation!
anyone helps?much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Because `0` could be interpreted as null pointer, which could be accepted by both the overloaded `test`. While `1` is an `int`, which could be accepted only by the 2nd overloaded `test`, that means `value` will be always `false`.

Comment: i just substitute the nullptr for 0,it okay.thanks！